# Source of "Immortalised in Prose, A God Among the Pages"

Tags: poetry, quote-source

I'm pretty sure this comes from an English poem, referring a woman's beauty. The author suggests that roses fade and wither, and that by describing her in written word keeps her alive forever.

That might be a misdirect, it was a long time ago I read it. The actual poem didn't really stick with me, but the last line did and I've been trying to find the origin:

Immortalised in prose, a god among the pages

Any ideas? Google has not been fruitful.

Comment: It sounds like that poem was inspired by Shakespeare's Sonnet 54. It talks about roses that fade and the beauty of a woman immortalised in verse. http://www.shakespeare-online.com/sonnets/54.html

Comment: Do any of [these poems](https://hellopoetry.com/words/immortalized/) match? It doesn't seem so, unless you're misremembering quite a bit ... the closest I found was "*in its solitude / a rose silently wilts / [...] / the paper on which they both decay pays no mind / [...] / immortalized in forgotten words*".